# Issue in loop through the all property through loop index in array

Tags: angular

I am implementing a single filter on all columns of the table. So any time a user searches anything the function should search the value in the whole array and return only filtered rows. That means it should check for a match in all property of array item.

In Angular 8, I bind my table by with an array that has 4 rows with multiple properties. My array looks like this.

```
export const Hero = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice', age: 30 },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco', age: 35}
  ];
```

Now when I try to filter out the rows I need to match the searchtext to all rows and all property (id, name, and age) of the array. Array items are loop through but the property name can not be looped because they are accessible by name only not by index.

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" class="searchBox" #txtSearch (keyup)="filterHerosKeyUp(txtSearch.value)" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
```

TS file code

```
filterHerosKeyUp(filter: string) { // without type info
   const data = this.Hero.slice();
   this.filteredValues = data.filter(item => item.id, name and age etc.)
}
```

Here I want to loop through all items for all properties (id, name, and age).

Please advise.

Comment: please create the stackblitz or post your code here?

Comment: your methods have different names in html and in ts file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` to loop through all values in object

try this:

```
filterHerosKeyUp(filter: string) { // without type info
   const data = this.Hero.slice();
   this.filteredValues = data.filter(item => {
       var keys = Object.keys(item);
       for(let key of keys){
           if(item[key] == filter)
               return true;
       }
       return false;
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mustahsan, but I dont want to use the properties ( Id, name or age). Can I loop on all available property in array. So if anytime I add or delete any property in array, I do not need to change filter code.

Comment: it worked for the complete match of the filter string, it should return if it not match completely too. I tried this -------------if                                                                                                                                          
                                             
                  ((item[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
                return true;
            }                                                                                                              but it gives error.

Comment: if(item[key].toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()) use this

Comment: Thanks again, this was not an issue of the functions, it was due to the try to convert an int value to toLowerCase(). I use JSON.stringify(item[key]); and it worked.